# JAX-RS compliant implementation on mobile devices

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, gluon-mobile

I'm writing an application that should run on both desktop and mobile and it needs to communicate with a server using REST. I'm Using Gluon Mobile.

The code I write on the client side is jax-rs-compliant and looks like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://www...").path("/login/...");
Future<Response> future = target.request().async().get();
Response response = future.get();
```

and I specify a dependency on an implementation like RESTEASY or Jersey clients.

Gluon Connect has REST implementation but it is not JAX-RS compliant:

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.create()
        .method("GET")
        .host("https://...")
        .path("/login/...")
...
```

It means that my client needs 2 code versions. I would like write once run anywhere like I get with the rest of my code. Is it possible? Is there a JAX-RS implementation I can use on android and ios? I need to tell gradle to use one implementation when building desktop and others for android and ios right?

Comment: I have this exact question and I'm hoping that someone can provide some clarifications regarding this. I'm working on an Android app and the server APIs were implemented in JAX-RS. I'm not aware of a JAX-RS compliant client for Android, I've tried Resteasy and Jersey but both seem to have some issues on Android. Does anyone have success implementing such a client on Android?

Comment: @BenZ. i think I saw Jersey for android, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Hey @Mark, thanks for responding.  I did extensive research after reading through various SO posts.  I was able to get RESTeasy and Jersey to compile successfully on Android, but both resulted in runtime crash when builder() is called.  I don't believe Android has a JAX-RS compliant library, and have implemented my solution using Retrofit instead.